# Is there a way to send post data using esky?

Tags: python, esky

Is it possible to send post data in esky?

```
#I need to be able to send post data in this request
app = esky.Esky(sys.executable,"https://example-app.com/downloads/")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, The best way would be to look in the source code and see if you find the option lurking around, it should be possible to subclass the esky finder class and get the behavior you are looking for.

[This pull request](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/pull/73/files) is sub classing the finder to get updates from amazon s3, it might help you out!

Comment: I don't trust myself to start changing the open source of esky, I would prefer that the makers of esky upload a new version, any way to contact them?

Comment: I am probably the most active member right now, having said that we are doing  a lot of catch up work. All i can say is have a go, do a pull request, we can comment and give feedback/review until the code is ready. Here is our github page https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky